# Node.js: Passport, checking if the user had already logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have this express router for users that logs in the users using the token system:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var Verify = require('./verify');

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username }),
      req.body.password, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({err: err});
        }
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {

            return res.status(200).json({status: 'Registration Successful!'});
        });
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }

      var token = Verify.getToken(user);
        res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);

});

module.exports = router;
```

The Verify file:

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('../config.js');

exports.getToken = function (user) {
    return jwt.sign(user, config.secretKey, {
        expiresIn: 3600
    });
};

exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, config.secretKey, function (err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        var err = new Error('No token provided!');
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

Now, I am validating if the user is logged in using the success attribute. I want my route to check if the user is already logged in the login route before going through the passport authentication. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this :

```
var auth = function(req, res, next){
   if (!req.isAuthenticated())
    res.send(401);
     else next();
   };
```

Comment: Can you please delete your answer so that I can delete this duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your route, for example:

```
app.route('/checkout', verifyOrdinaryUser, function(req, res) {
});
```

That function will run before the callback with the request and response objects, so if it's not authenticated, it will do whatever you tell it to do, if it's authenticated, it will continue

Comment: Um, could you pls tell me how it would fit into my code?

Comment: Just like that, you already have the function to check the token "verifyOrdinaryUser" right?. Add it to your route like I showed you before

Comment: Um, that's not my question actually. I just want to redirect the user if he is already logged in. And let him through to the login page if he hasn't. Adding that call back to my route will block the user if not already logged in. This pretty much makes login impossible.

Comment: You can change your code to redirect the user if he is already logged in to the main page or if he is not logged in then redirect it to the login page

Comment: Yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Oh, I found the answer on SO. Can you please delete your answer so that I can delete this duplicate question?Thanks!